# Django: Change url in Class based view GET request

Tags: python, django, url

Hi I have two forms which render to the same template.

When i submit my runsearchform, it takes me to the page:

```
 localhost/reporting/?run=2&submit=Search+for+run
```

where 2 is my run PK id

How can I modify this URL into something like

```
 localhost/reporting/run_name
```

where run_name = a unique field in my Run model that is not the primary key

views:

```
class ReportView(View):

    runsearchform = RunSearchForm
    samplesearchform = SampleSearchForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        runsearchform = self.runsearchform()
        context = {'runsearchform': runsearchform}

        if 'run' in request.GET:
            samplesearchform = self.samplesearchform(request.GET)
            context = {'samplesearchform': samplesearchform}


        return render(request, 'results/reporting.html', context)



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        """ do stuff with samples...
        """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the `run_name` in your `urls.py` such as:

```
url(r'^(?i)reporting/(?P<run_name>[a-z0-9]+)/$', myapp.views.ReportView.as_view())
```

And then your view could receive the parameter such as:

```
class ReportView(View):

    runsearchform = RunSearchForm
    samplesearchform = SampleSearchForm

    def get(self, request, run_name):
        # Load the report based on the run_name, and do something with it
```

When a request is made to e.g. `localhost/reporting/myreport`, the `run_name` argument would be set to `myreport`.